# Idea behind the tangential vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, differential-forms

I am currently reading a chapter about Pfaff forms, but not really understand, why the author introduces tangential vector spaces - the definition seems rather redundant to me, if I didn't overlook something.

Let $ U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, and $ p \in U$ then: $T_p (U) $ is called the tangential vector space in point $p$ - the set of all tangent vectors $\alpha ' (0)$ cont. diff able through point p,

$\alpha : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to U $ and $ \alpha(0)  = p $

This implicates: $ T_p(U) = \mathbb{R}^n $ as: $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n :t \to p +tv $ is a tangential vector

So why is this vector space needed?

Directly after that the dual space  $T_p^* (U) $ to $T_p(U)$ is defined (which is used & useful as the following chapters tell) - however I don't really see the idea / the need to go the way over the tangential space, when it is equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

I am afraid I miss out an key idea but this tangential space and if I don't get it, then I won't understand all following definitions well and overall miss a lot.

Thus I would be very happy, if someone understands my confusion and may clear things up. 
As always I am happy about any constructive comment or answer.

Comment: The point is: The definition works in somewhat more general settings than just open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Ah, mhm I read this thread here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405585/tangential-space-of-a-differentiable-manifold-is-always-mathbb-rn?rq=1

And I became a bit unsure, if it helped, as this may cover the same topic, but approaches it with terms I am not yet very familiar / comfortable with

Comment: To expand a little bit on the comment by @HagenvonEitzen, try to replace $U$ by the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. You will find that the tangent space at any point is $n-1$-dimensional, and can in fact be identified with the hyperplane touching the sphere at the given point. And yet, there is no sensible way to identify all these spaces with $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ in a coherent way.

Answer (score 1):

The idea makes more sense if you think about surfaces.

For example take $U \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ open and some sufficiently nice function $f: U \to \mathbb R$. Then, the graph $G_f = \{(x,y,f(x,y))\}$ of $f$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ and one can consider the tangential vector space to a point $p \in G_f$ which would then be defined to

$$T_p(G_f) = \{ \alpha'(0) | \alpha: (-\varepsilon , \varepsilon) \to G_f \text{ cont. diff. } ,  \alpha(0) = p \}$$

In this case $T_p(G_f)$ (or rather $T_p(G_f) + p$) can really be interpreted as a plane which is tangential to $G_f$ at $p$.